# Im trying to get a specific cell from a dynamic table that has dynamic ids

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to automate using Selenium webdriver and C# to enter values in to a  dynamically created table that has dynamic ids that are never the same. I have tried many ways to get a specific cell index but cannot do so. At the moment im just tabing my way in to the cell and enter data in that manner. Please let me know if you need more info. thanks

```html
<div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" ui-grid-one-bind-id-grid="rowRenderIndex + '-' + col.uid + '-cell'" class="ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-00IW" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }"
  role="gridcell" ui-grid-cell="" tabindex="-1" id="1519216674244-0-uiGrid-00IW-cell" aria-selected="true">
  <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope ui-grid-cell-focus xh-highlight"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this for a test? IMO this sounds like a test that is trying to be too clever and do too much. Is the **html** you provided one cell of the table? Does any part of the `id` indicate location within the grid? Can you determine which cell it is relative to the table element it's contained in? For example, if it's the 5th `div` under the table, you know it's row 2 column 1, etc...

Comment: Hi 
This is the Id /div[@id='1519235513934-0-uiGrid-011N-cell'].
The long number is dynamic and is the specific table on the page as there are 3 separate tables the 011N gives the specific column which is also dynamic and the 0 is the row number which is static

Comment: Looks like you can just use a helper function that takes a row and column and returns an element or BY object using a css selector or xpath. For example, css `"div[id*='" + row + column + "-cell']"`. I'm assuming here the two digits are row, and the two letters are column. You could also use `id$` instead of `id*` if you know the id for sure ends with `-cell`.